# DCO signing issue, src refspec does not match any, Failed to push some refs

Tags: git, github

Trying to follow the instructions at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/7469/checks?check_run_id=25144990

I was able to signoff the commit, but when I execute the second command **"git push --force origin patch-1"**, I get below error in the git console :

```
$ git push --force origin patch-1
    error: src refspec patch-1 does not match any.
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/akmalick/gradle.git'
```

I have looked up similar questions over stackoverflow, but they don't seem to help my cause. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I see you have branch [patch-1](https://github.com/akmalick/gradle/tree/patch-1) at Github; do you have it in your local repository?

Comment: @phd running command **git rev-parse --verify --quiet patch-1** gives no output. Does that mean, I don't have it in my local repo ?

Comment: Yes. You need to fetch the branch from Github: `git fetch origin patch-1:patch-1`.

Comment: Thanks@phd Did that  and running the command **git rev-parse --verify --quiet patch-1** gives me a hash  but the git status now tells me this : `On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: `git fetch` fetches commits but doesn't switch branches. To make the branch current run `git checkout patch-1`.

Comment: Thanks a ton @phd

done that. switched to patch-1 then executed the command `git push --force origin patch-1`. And everything seems to have gone right. Also, the pull request page now shows : `DCO Successful in -1m — DCO`, only the CI build is in progress :`Pending — The Travis CI build is in progress`. So I think its correct to assume that now my pr should be through. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the accepted answer.